# Unknown script in my webpage

Tags: javascript, virus, spyware

Today I saw one white pixel on my website's background, at first I thought that's it's my monitor, but it didn't appear on another website. Then I inspected this pixel with firebug and found out this:

```
<script src="http://i.swebdpjs.info/opt_content.js?v=opt_1405411874643&partner=sweb&channel=sweb&sset=1&appTitle=&sset=1&ip=127.0.0.1" type="application/x-javascript">
```

I never added this script, and the strangest part is that it doesn't appear in my source files, and this website is not on hosting company, it's on my localhost. Does anyone has knowledge on what might it be? http://swebdpjs.info points to http://www.limelight.com/.

Comment: Check your browser plugins, a virus has probably injected itself into your browser and now puts that script on every webpage you visit.

Comment: first step of xss attacks. Beware of it!

Comment: If you're using firefox, hold shift while you start it and it will prompt you to start in safe mode or reset. Start in safe mode and see if the pixel is still there (I bet it won't be). That being true would indicate that you have a bad plugin or extension. There will be some stuff installed on your computer that shouldn't be. Run virus/malware/etc scans over EVERYTHING

Comment: @Avery A lot of plugins insert scripts, that does not mean they are bad.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! it proved to be true, when I opened firefox in safe mode, that pixel was gone:) but yeah, I will need to get malwarebytes again, nod32 isn't good enough.

Comment: @jgillich This is true, but I've dealt with the exact same thing as OP before, and it's a nasty one to deal with. The white pixel is usually an indication that an ad was injected, but removed by adblock (some combo of the two causes the pixel).

Comment: @AMD_Paulius Did you read my answer? The script includes tons of mentions of DealPly.

Comment: Yes I read, but it's not possible that it was me who installed DealPly, I never even visited that page, and it's also impossible that it was someone else, as I'm the only one who has access to my computer:]

Answer (score 0):

It's a script inserted by [DealPly](http://www.dealply.com/), which you probably have installed.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments above i'm posting this answer

1. xss attacks.
2. Be Sure that you have right anti virus tools installed on your machine.
3. If not contact you administrator to do that.
4. Take backup of only code using configuration managers.

Hope this helps...